# Why adb is under platform tools?

Tags: android

I was going through ADB in android. Why it is under Platform Tools? No matter, what is the platform, it should be able to install app on emulator or real device... then it should come under tools directory  right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `platform-tools/` directory contains binaries that are specific to a development machine's OS. For example, I am running Ubuntu Linux, and so I have Linux versions of **`adb`**, etc. Somebody else running Windows would have **`adb.exe`**, etc.

The `tools/` directory is mostly shell scripts and batch files. It used to be that both were shipped to all development machines. I see that nowadays, they do split them up by development OS (e.g., I have **`android`**, not **`android.bat`**).